# C++ how to "un-use" a library reference?

Tags: c++, std, using

In a program I am making heavy use of the std library. I want to name a function `less()`, however this is already taken in `std`. Is there a line I can add after `using namespace std;` that will clear out `less()` for declaration later.

Currently I am receiving "error: reference to 'less' is ambiguous".

I am aware that I can list out everything that I am using (e.g. `using std::cout;`), I just wanted to ask if there is a 'negated' version of this.

Thank you, Daniel

Comment: this is a perfect example of why you should never use 'using namespace std', see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Comment: No.   Once done, the effects of a `using` directive (like `using namespace std`) cannot be undone.   The solutions are either to avoid the `using` directive, or fully qualify the names  (e.g.  call your function `::less` if it is not in any namespace, or `yournamespace::less` if it is in `yournamespace`).

Answer (score 9):

You can use explicitly `::less` or use `using ::less` in inner scope.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
void less();

void func1() {
    ::less();
}

void func2() {
    using ::less;
    less();
}
```

Overall, instead, consider removing `using namespace std;` from your code and decorate your code with `std::` everywhere where it is needed.

Answer (score 4):

This is easy to answer: no, that is impossible. You have to avoid polluting your namespaces in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a line I can add after using namespace std; that will clear out less() for declaration later.

No, but what you can do instead is to not write `using namespace std;` in the first place.

Or alternatively, you can refer to your `less` with a qualified name using the scope resolution operator.